# view sharepoint site outsite the vmware workstation

Tags: sharepoint-2010, windows-server-2008, vmware-workstation

I am running windows server 2008 in vmware workstation and there I have installed sharepoint 2010.
How can I view a sharepoint site from my host machine, so from my windows 7?

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the network configuration you assigned to your VM. If you didn't isolate your VM, you should be able to ping it from your host (assuming they share the same network settings - subnet mask, gateway, ip class, ...) and access your SharePoint site from the host.

Also make sure that the native firwall on your server is allowing inbound / outbound connection with the relevant port (at least :80).

Cheers.

Comment: @Franocis - thanks a lot for your help. I can ping my vmware machine and I can view the site in the host machine. The only change I did was that I set a static IP address for my guest os and now it is working. thanks again